# CSS background-image doesn't display in chrome, works in other browsers

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, background-image

I have a div created dynamically on pageload with javascript. it works correctly in IE9 and Firefox, but when loaded in chrome it doesn't display the background image. Is this a bug in chrome, or am I missing something?

```
#dateTime{  
    background-image:url('datebg_transparent.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:top right; 
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    position:fixed;
    color:white;
    font: Times;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width: 50%; 
    height: 20%;
}
```

heres the js that creates it if that matters. the function is called multiple times to reset the date/time displayed in the div, so it first checks to see if the div exists yet or not

```
    var dateDiv = document.getElementById('dateTime');
    if (!dateDiv) {
        dateDiv = document.createElement('div');
        dateDiv.id = 'dateTime';
        document.body.appendChild(dateDiv);
    }
```

Comment: size of image you are using?

Comment: @AspiringAqib it's 736 x 70

Comment: Can we get a demo? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: or if you can't then link to site? because not for all but can we solve problem for you only if we can :P

Comment: @AspiringAqib also I've just realized that the image does actually load, but only flickers for a second then is hidden

Comment: but here, i didn't noticed any flickers of image! check my answer if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well got the solution! you have this:

```
dateDiv.style.width = "50%";
```

change it to :

```
dateDiv.style.width = "736px";
```

[image]

Comment: i only checked it for chrome!

Comment: well this is annoying, I guess somethings wrong with my chrome. I even just updated to the new beta, and it's still not showing on mine. but if others can at least view it properly in chrome, I won't be too worried about it. Thanks!

Comment: woah man i edited the code and then it got showing! `dateDiv.style.width = "736px";`

Comment: yeah its still not showing in chrome. but it shows in every other browser, including my mobile devices. so i'll have to figure out whats wrong with my browser, but I'm marking your answer as helpful anyways

Comment: no well, man its working on my lappy :) and i also attached a picture with my answer!